# Linux SCTP implementation status

Tags: linux, sctp

Some time ago I had used SCTP on Linux and now I want to use it again in new project. The problem is that, lksctp seems to be dead, there were no updated since 2009 (according to git). In this time few important things changed in SCTP draft, so lksctp is now out of date ([API for example](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tsvwg-sctpsocket-26))

I tried to find other implementation of this protocol, but it looks, that lksctp is the only one. Doy you have any information about SCTP future on Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lksctp is enough good for you to use. If you have some question or want new features(must be reasonable), linux will implement them.

The API of sctp is still in draft. But, almost functions in draft are all implemented in linux. sctp maintainer Vlad Yasevich maybe be more busy doing other things for over half of year, even one year. But other folks still can help you.

Answer (score 5):

The lksctp project first developed the Linux implementation but it is now part of the core linux Kernel and maintained there. This explains why there is little activity on the lksctp project and it does not indicate that the implementation is dead at all. Indeed I am responsible for a product line for which the Linux SCTP implementation is a central, and very reliable, component.

Answer (score 2):

According to this SO answer, [Does SCTP works as advertised using Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825109/does-sctp-works-as-advertised-using-linux) LKSTCP is the way to go.

Note that the document that you linked to is an Internet draft, which means that the API has *NOT* changed. It only means that it might change if the draft becomes an RFC without being changed. If you want to track the work being done in Internet drafts then you are in experimental territory. I suggest that your best bet is to contact the authors of the draft and ask them if they know of anyone working on adding their changes to LKSTCP. Then you can work together with them on this.

Comment: V. Yasevich is one of the draft authors. Also he is the maintainer of lksctp. So, maybe you don't need to ask them and can know the answer. :-)